# Kivy - creating an Image Button

Tags: python, kivy

iam trying to create a custom ImageButton in kivy and iam open for recommendations,this is what i have so far:

```
class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    def __init__(self, source, ID, on_press_bg=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.main_source = source
        self.on_press_background = on_press_bg
        self.source = source
        self.id = ID

    def on_press(self):
        self.source = self.on_press_background
        self.canvas.add(Color(0, 0,0,0))
        self.canvas.add(Rectangle(size=(self.width, self.height), pos=self.pos))
```

i would like the Imagebutton to display an another image once pressed,for some reason the color changes and i cannot see the new image, (i have a transparent background images),so i was wondering how can i do it,if you have any other suggestions or a better way to do it i dont mind too,thank you very much!

Comment: The `Button` class already does that. Use `background_normal` for the normal background image and `background_down` for the image when the `Button` is pressed.